# React Native - Filter JSON based on another const JSON inside FlatList

Tags: json, react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a FlatList and set leftAvatar image based on the value of my fetched JSON and my const JSON. My example:

```
    const myicons = [
          {
            title: 'Cotton',
            file: require('../assets/images/cotton.png'),
          },
          {
            title: 'Beef',
            file: require('../assets/images/beef.png'),
          },
        ];
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              leftAvatar={{ source: myicons.filter(myitem => myitem.title === item.product)[0].file }}
              title={item.description}
              subtitle={`${item.product} ${item.description}`}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.index}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

When the code is as above, I get an error of undefined for item.product, while if i hardcode it as myitem.title === 'Beef' it works like a charm. The next lines also work fine with item.*

What is the right syntax for this? I believe this is the best way to go, but, if I don't surpass this, I will have to set the file value in the fetched JSON which means more KB's for the user and I don't want that.

EDIT
My this.data.state values are

```
[{"date":"Thu, 31 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Banana, Europe,($/kg)","index":0,"price":0.96277169112575,"product":"Bananas"},{"date":"Thu, 31 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Banana, US,($/kg)","index":1,"price":1.1505360625,"product":"Bananas"},{"date":"Thu, 31 Oct 2019 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Bananas, Central American and Ecuador, FOB U.S. Ports, US$ per metric ton","index":2,"price":1136.5001201057,"product":"Bananas"},{"date":"Wed, 30 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Beef - Choice 1","index":3,"price":192.98,"product":"Beef"},{"date":"Wed, 30 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Beef - Select 1","index":4,"price":169.31,"product":"Beef"},{"date":"Thu, 31 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Beef,($/kg)","index":5,"price":4.15019715,"product":"Beef"},{"date":"Wed, 30 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Butter, AA Chicago, lb","index":6,"price":2.425,"product":"Butter"},{"date":"Thu, 31 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Cocoa,($/kg)","index":7,"price":2.65994,"product":"Cocoa"},{"date":"Thu, 31 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT","description":"Coffee Price, Arabica, cents/kg","index":8,"price":2.989685182,"product":"Coffee"}]
```

Comment: can you share your ```this.state.data``` values

Comment: Just added it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, the first object that passes to flatlist

```
{
    date: "Thu, 31 May 2018 00:00:00 GMT",
    description: "Banana, Europe,($/kg)",
    index: 0,
    price: 0.96277169112575,
    product: "Bananas"
}
```

Now your filter function will like this

```
myicons.filter(myitem => myitem.title === 'Bananas')[0].file
```

But you don't have any value in `myicons` array according to `Bananas`. So it return an `undefined`.

In order to fix this error, modify your `myicons` to handle all titles or provide a default property to display when your result is`undefined`

**Important**

You can use find instead of filter in JS

```
myicons.find(myitem => myitem.title === item.product).file
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: You were right! It was a mistake of 's' in the end of the product. Thank you very much!